# How to save GLSurfaceView rendering to file?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, gpu, glsurfaceview

I'm using VideoSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView to render filtered video. I'm doing it buy changing the fragment shader according to my needs. Now I would like to save/render the video after the changes to a file of the same format(Ex. mp4 - h264) but couldn't find how to do it.

I am using this library - https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects.

Any experts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and use the [MediaProjection API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html). Here is an [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture) for this api. Notice: this might not work on the new emulators.

Comment: This is not permanent solutions. I want to keep both original and filter video and need to save in memory.